# MySql stored procedure Combinations

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Si I have this MySql stored procedure which I use for gridview filter. For 3 columns I have to write this many combinations of queries. I have to use filters on 7 columns and that would make 7x7x7x7x7x7x7 number combinations. Is there a better way to make this happen?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetApprovedData`
(in siteValue varchar(45),
 in skillValue varchar(100), in shiftValue varchar(100))
 BEGIN

 IF siteValue IS NULL and skillValue IS NULL and shiftValue IS NULL THEN 
  select * from approved;

 ELSEIF siteValue IS NULL and skillValue IS NULL and shiftValue IS NOT NULL    THEN
  select * from approved where shift = shiftValue;

 ELSEIF siteValue IS NULL and skillValue IS NOT NULL and shiftValue IS NULL THEN
  select * from approved where skill = skillValue;

 ELSEIF siteValue IS NOT NULL and skillValue IS NULL and shiftValue IS NULL THEN
  select * from approved where site = siteValue;

 ELSEIF siteValue IS NULL and skillValue IS NOT NULL and shiftValue IS NOT NULL THEN
  select * from approved where skill = skillValue and shift = shiftValue;

ELSEIF siteValue IS NOT NULL and skillValue IS NOT NULL and shiftValue IS NULL THEN
  select * from approved where site = siteValue and skill = skillValue;

ELSEIF siteValue IS NOT NULL and skillValue IS NULL and shiftValue IS NOT NULL THEN
  select * from approved where site = siteValue and shift = shiftValue;

ELSE        
  select * from approved where site = siteValue and skill = skillValue and shift = shiftValue;
END IF;

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the parameter `IS NULL` or if the column value for a row matches the parameter's value.

```
SELECT *
       FROM approved
       WHERE (sitevalue IS NULL
               OR site = sitevalue)
             AND (skillvalue IS NULL
                   OR skill = skillvalue)
             AND (shiftvalue IS NULL
                   OR shift = shiftvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ifnull() function in the query `WHERE` clause instead. This will handle NULL values in your parameters without all of the `IF` statements.

```
SELECT *
  FROM approved
 WHERE site = ifnull(siteValue, site)
   AND shift = ifnull(shiftValue, shift)
   AND skill = ifnull(skillValue, skill)
```